# How to grab top 3 from a MySQL Fetch array

Tags: php, mysql

Simply, I want to be able to fetch the TOP 3 arrays being returned in a MySQL fetch array;

```
   $getTopStats = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE rank <= '2' ORDER BY activity_points DESC LIMIT 20");
    while($topSpats = mysql_fetch_array($getTopStats)){
// $sizeotar will return either s (small) or l (large) - (large for the first top 3 users, and then small for the rest of the users)
echo '<img src="imaging/image?figure=' . $topSpats['look'] . '&size=' . $sizeotar . '&direction=2&head_direction=2&gesture=sml" align="left"></td> <td width="195px"><a href="#"><b>'.$topSpats['username'].'</b></a><br />'.$topSpats['activity_points'].' duckets';

    }
```

I am not to familiar with mysql fetch arrays, so I am not too good with doing so.

Comment: Two problems in these small lines already: outdated Mysql client library, HTML creation without proper encoding.

Answer (score 2):

if So why you added `LIMIT 20` to the query

```
SELECT *
FROM users
WHERE rank <= '2'
ORDER BY activity_points DESC LIMIT 3
```

If you want to do it with yout query.Just use

[array_slice](http://php.net/array_slice) returns a slice of an array

```
array_slice($array, 0, 3)
```

Comment: Because I want it to display up to 20 users, but I want the top 3 to come out with a custom variable ($sizeotar) so I can have it automatically choose between small and large (small for the rest of the users, large for top 3)

Comment: `array_slice` won't work with `mysql_fetch_array` unless you first create the array with all fetches.

Comment: @Reverb: Count a counter. Start with 0. Count up one per each while loop. Then when larger then three, you know it's the small one. Until there, it's the large one. But I must admit your question was not really clear about that.

Comment: @hakre my apologies. I am just not all that familiar with MySQL Fetch Array.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right with the comments then given, this could work:

Add a counter, so you can decide which string to use:

```
for ($counter = 0; $topSpats = mysql_fetch_array($getTopStats); $counter++)
{
    $sizetoar = $counter < 3 ? 'l' : 's';
    ...
```

Within the first three loops, the counter will be: 0, 1 and 2.